# Is reference a constant?

Tags: swift

I have following code:

```
class Employee {

    var name: String = String()
    var surname: String = String()

    init(name: String, surname: String) {

        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    }

}
```

create an object with the let keyword:

```
let john = Employee(name: "John", surname: "Adams")
```

My question is, what is here a constant, the reference or the object?

Comment: Try it.  Can you reassign the `name` property in `john`?

Comment: yes, so the reference is constant right?

Comment: Yes, you can't assign another `Employee` instance to `john`, but you can change it.

Comment: The answer is different for structs, because they are value types, not reference types.

Comment: strictly speaking, the left side of an expression is constant  representing some value or a reference to value. In your case it represents constant reference. the value of john is immutable, but properties of the referenced instance of Empoyee class are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The reference is the constant.

Infact if you try to change it

```
john = Employee(name: "aName", surname: "aSurname")
```

you get the following pretty explicative compiler error.

```
error: cannot assign to value: 'john' is a 'let' constant
john = Employee(name: "aName", surname: "aSurname")
~~~~ ^
```

On the other hand the `properties` of the object are declared `var` and can be changed

```
john.name = "another name"
```